# Build errors on a copied operating system in a chroot

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, gcc, chroot

I'm in a bit of an interesting situation.

In an attempt to have root access on my school's physics network computers, I ended up creating a chroot environment, using fakeroot and fakechroot. As every source I've read seems to suggest that debootstrap, a tool to install Debian in a subdirectory, requires root, I went ahead with the method listed [**here**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-chroot-command-examples-usage-syntax/) - this entails copying, yes, using `cp`, to copy terminal commands and their dependencies into this environment.

I've used this sleek trick so much that I've pretty much copied the entire operating system (Debian+a slew of physics tools) into a subdirectory, a subdirectory that pretends to be an operating system, where I get to pretend I'm sudo/God.

Surprisingly, many things work. They didn't at first, but coffee is good at killing bugs.

Unfortunately, I'm a little bit stuck. Whenever I make use of python (apt-get, et cetera), I get:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
```

Most fixes to this problem involved actually setting the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables, which did not fix anything. The other common solution is to just build python from source, which I try, but I receive the following when I try to build anything:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

The attached config.log file for this error can be found [**here**](http://pastebin.com/raw/8UCK6mMf).

Any help would be dearly appreciated. Also, if you have advice to completely avoid this situation or get debootstrap working without root, that would be great as well.

---

*Update1*: Tried to simplify things a bit - tried to compile a simple c file and got another commonly listed error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Tried `whereis` to locate it - turns out cc1 does not exist in my environment! I will now continue to slave away...

*Update2*: Created a soft link from gcc to cc1 (`ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/cc1`), which put a light bandage on the volcano - I now have unrecognized command line options when I gcc a sample file, including `'-quiet'`, `'-imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu'`, and `'-auxbase'`.

*Update3*: Got compiler to work! Fixed all of the above problems by trying different compilers (i.e. gcc-4.4, gcc-4.7, gcc-ar) - the last of which game me a different error - that it could not find a required plugin. This clued me into the fact that not all of the c libraries had been copied over from the base OS. I fixed this which fixed my problem (one of many).

My new problem is an (apparent) lack of GMP, MPFR, and MPC. These are needed to rebuild gcc.

*Update4*: Compiled all three libraries. The next problem in the gcc build process was not being able to find crt1.o, crti.o, crtn.o, -lgcc, -lgcc_s, and -lc. This was fixed by setting `--enable-multilib` as a flag for the configure script.

Comment: Don't try to be root on your school's computer (or anyone else computer) without permission. This is a legal offense in most countries (2 years of jail in France, [art 323-1 Code Pénal](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006418316&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070719)... )

Comment: I should hopefully be good - fakeroot and fakechroot aren't actually putting me in root control of the entire system. The environment I created with fakechroot can be thought of as something like a virtual machine - so it's completely isolated and independent from the rest of the computer. It's just a way to simplify the creation of the complex build system I want to make. Although if I go offline for a while, you should send help :P

Comment: Your softlink should be `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/cc`

Comment: Ask the people in charge for help setting up a virtual machine for your use. Less work overall, doing it above board *will* save you grief later on.

Comment: ^That's a good idea and I will look into it after the winter break. However right now I will push on in drafting an appeal to my stubbornness... Just now, by some miracle I built all three dependencies.